# PHP + MySQL + Spanish

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, encoding, collation

My system deals with spanish data. I am using laravel + mysql. My database collation is latin1 - default collation and my tables structure looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=298 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Have a few questions:

1. I load data from file to db. Is it a good practice to
   utf8_encode($name) before inserting to db? I am currently doing so,
   else some comparison throw error : `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='`
2. If using utf8_encode is the way to go, do i need to utf8_encode even name i want to search? i.e. select... where name =
   utf8_encoded(name)?
3. Is there any flaws or better way to handle the above? As i doing spanish for the first time (characters with accents).

Comment: I was under the impression that `VARCHAR`s in MySQL were UTF8 by default so you would not expect to have to use `utf8_encode` when utilising them.

Comment: @MartinParkin updated with the error that i get when i insert data without utf8 encoding. And then selecting using = filter.

Answer (score 0):

Your `product.name` column has the character set `latin1`. You know that. It also has the collation `latin1_swedish_ci`. That's the default. The original developers of MySQL are Swedish.  Because you're working in Spanish, you probably want to use `latin1_spanish_ci` for your collation; it sorts `Ñ` after `N`. The other Latin-language collations sort them together.

Because your `product.name` column is stored in latin1, it is a *bad*, not a *good*, idea to use `utf8_encode()` on text before storing it to that column.

Your best course of action, especially if your application is new, is to make the character set for all columns `utf8mb4`. That means changing the defined character set of your `name` column.   Then you can convert text strings to unicode before storing them.

You probably would be wise to make the default collation of each table `utf8mb4_spanish_ci` as well. Collations get baked into indexes for `varchar()` columns.  (If you're working in traditional Spanish, in which `ch` is a distinct letter, use `utf8mb4_spanish2_ci`.)